# Unity - Resources.LoadAll in EditorWindow

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Anyone knows how to use Resources.LoadAll or another method like this, in EditorWindow?

I have that error: `LoadAll can only be called from the main thread`.

Generaly I create node editor, where i need all items in my resources.

[image]

---

This is how I use my static method:

```
foreach (var item in DataManager.Items.All<Food>())
{
      _foodItems.Add(item.Name);
}
```

This is my static method:

```
internal static IEnumerable<T> All<T>() where T : BaseItem
{
       return Resources.LoadAll<T>(itemsPaths[typeof (T)]);
}
```

BaseItem is public abstract class with some public variables.

```
public abstract class BaseItem : Datablock
{
     #region Data

     /// <summary>
     /// Game item name.
     /// </summary>
     public string Name;
```

Ohhh and `QuestTaskNode` class where I want use `Resources.LoadAll` inherits from `ScriptableObject`

Comment: Everything here is wrong.  You can't use statics at all in Unity.  Unity is an ECS system and has no connection at all to OO.  You are simply **writing components** which are **attached to** "GameObject" items.

Answer (score 1):

Bad:

```
Class BadCode{
  Resources.LoadAll(....);
}
```

Bad:

```
Class BadCode{
    BadCode(){
     Resources.LoadAll(....);
   }
}
```

Good:

```
Class GoodCode{

  void putUnityAPIInsideAFunction()
  {
      Resources.LoadAll(....);
  }
}
```

Just put the Unity API code inside a function.Also don't put it in a class constructor that inherits from `MonoBehaviour`. You will get the-same error because these are not called on the main `Thread`.

Comment: Already i have static method: 

`internal static IEnumerable<T> All<T>() where T : BaseItem
{
        return Resources.LoadAll<T>(itemsPaths[typeof (T)]);
}`

And i used it like this:

`foreach (var item in DataManager.Items.All<Food>())
{
        _foodItems.Add(item.Name);
}`

Sorry, i'm new and i don't know how corrent use formatting here.

Comment: I inherits from `ScriptableObject`.

Comment: Edit your question and add the code there. Also add the `BaseItem` class. You need to add something I can use to find out what's going on. Also make sure to add the programming language to your question in the future

Comment: Ok sorry for that.